# Bootstrap 4 Grid - Aligning elements closer to each other

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Somewhat new to Bootstrap and I'm having a hard time trying to align three elements within a row.  I'm trying to put an edit button, an icon that is a link, and then the chevron that opens up the panel together at the right end of the row.  The chevron is fine, but I can't figure out how to get the other buttons closer together.

[image]

Here's the code

```
<header class="card-header card-header-approval expensesheet-header">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <label class="h6" for="StatusDisplayName">@Model.ExpenseSheets[i].AccountingCode</label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-1" style="padding-left: 2px;padding-right: 2px;">
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditExpenseSheet", "Project", new { id = Model.ExpenseSheets[i].Id })
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-1  justify-content-center">
      <a id="detailModal"
        href="#"
        class="fa fa-sticky-note fa-2x AddNoteClick">
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-1 collapse-chevron text-right">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" class="collapsed" data-target="#expCollapsePanel_@i" href="#">
     <span class="fa fa-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
    </div>
 </div>
</header>
```

Ideally I'd like to get the edit button, note icon, and chevron right next to each other at the end of the row.  I feel like this should be easy but I'm still figuring out the whole Bootstrap grid layout.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the new Bootstrap 4 [auto-layout](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#auto-layout-columns) columns. The `col-auto` will "shrink" to fit its content. The `col` will "grow" to fill the width.

```
<header class="card-header card-header-approval expensesheet-header">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md">
            <label class="h6" for="StatusDisplayName">AccountingCode</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-auto">
            Edit
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-auto justify-content-center">
            <a id="detailModal" href="#" class="fa fa-sticky-note fa-2x AddNoteClick">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-auto collapse-chevron text-right">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" class="collapsed" data-target="#expCollapsePanel_@i" href="#">
                <span class="fa fa-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/8QhiaNoGSp

Answer (score 0):

don't use columns all the time ! BS4 columns are designed to draw spaces on screen, not position each element !

Use flexboxes everytime you need to align items.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,400i,500,500i,700" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row my-4">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Bootstrap 4 - Aligning elements closer to each other</h1>
        <p class="lead">by djibe.</p>
        <p class="text-muted">(thx to BS4)</p>
        <p class="lead">
          Tutorial
        </p>
        <ol>
          <li>Just use standard Bootstrap 4 classes and layout</li>
          <li>Create a div like this : <code>&lt;div class="d-flex align-items-center">&lt;/div></code></li>
          <li>In this div place all your elements each one placed in a semantic HTML5 tag (ex: span, p, div, i)</li>
          <li>When you want a set of elements to be aligned right, apply the BS4 class .ml-auto to the extreme left of these (in this case the #detailModal).<br><small> Or place all the elements in a div and apply ml-auto to this div<br> or use .justify-content-between on the container if there are only 2 elements in the div</small></li>
          <li>Apply margins for each element using BS4 mr-*, my-* or mx-* (Spacing utilities)</li>
          <li>Et voilà</li>
        </ol>

      </div>
      <div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <h2>
        Demo
      </h2>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
            <p class="mb-0">
              Headend Equipment - Contract labour - $9962.00
            </p>
            <a id="detailModal" href="#" class="ml-auto mr-3 fa fa-sticky-note fa-2x AddNoteClick">
      </a>
            <a data-toggle="collapse" class="collapsed" data-target="#expCollapsePanel_@i" href="#">
     <span class="fa fa-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```